# Expected value for minimum denominator of arbitrarily chosed rational out of a ball of fixed radius to complex plane

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

So I have a research problem which states that we compute the probability mass function of the random variable which returns the smallest denominator of a reduced fraction in a randomly chosen real interval of radius $\frac{\delta}{2}$ and my advisor proved the expected value of the minimum denominator to be $\frac{16}{\pi^2 \sqrt{\delta}}$ as $\delta \to 0$. I am asked to extend this to the complex case where a random open ball of radius $\delta$ is chosen and we would like for the min expected value of the norm of a denominator of a randomly chosen Gaussian rational in the ball. I do not know where to even begin with this, any hints or tips as this is my first research project. I know $\Bbb{Q}^2$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$ so there exists infinitely many Gaussian rationals in any arbitrary chosen ball of fixed radius. Any hints in the right direction greatly appreciated. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.12668.pdf) is a link to the paper.

I've read the paper maybe $300$ times thus far and can. barely grasp the notion of Farrey fractions (which from my understanding is all reduced fractions between $0$ and $1$ such that the denominator is less than a given, fixed, natural number). Also, I am unfamiliar with big-oh notation which appears in the paper.  Basically would like to know what changes need to be made to the case on $\Bbb{R}$ to swap the result so it holds for $\Bbb{C}$. I have been staring at this paper for weeks and have made zero progress.

Comment: I think a visit to your advisor is in order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Im just so scared because ive made no progress, I just need a tip or hint as to how to attack a research problem.

Comment: That's why you have an advisor. Your advisor is the person in the best place to tell you what you need to brush up on, and where to find the materials you need to bring you to where you can understand, and go beyond, the results in the paper.

Comment: I sympathize with Gerry's answer but advisors can of course be terrible and scary. However, maybe come up with at least one concrete question that is in the direction of improving your understanding like: "Can you recommend any notes or textbooks that go through Farey fractions and sequences in detail for someone who has never worked with them?" And ask your advisor this question. (Or MSE or MO)

Comment: @T_M he’s already given me sources to reference , is it ok to ask him to give me a hint or something on how to begin even?